# Struts Hello world example : There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name error

Tags: struts2, struts2-namespace, action-mapping

i am absolute beginner to Struts2. I am tying to follow tutorials on struts web site. i followed [this tutorial](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/hello-world-using-struts-2.html). i have some trouble with it. i created dynamic web project on eclipse. Then i followed the tutorial. However when i run the example i get the following error.

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [hello] associated with context path [/Hello_World_Struts_2]. - [unknown location]
```

i have the following directory structure

[image]

And my struts.xml file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

  <package name="basicstruts2" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

  <action name="index">
    <result>/index.jsp</result>
  </action>

  <action name="hello" class="org.apache.struts.helloworld.action.HelloWorldAction" method="execute">
    <result name="SUCCESS">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
  </action>

</package>

</struts>
```

thanks for your responses.

Comment: i tried to put it inside code block but i could not make it. Now, it is ok, i think.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `struts.xml` configuration file needs to be on the classpath (as opposed to in `WEB-INF`).

The linked tutorial assumes a Maven build and states the `struts.xml` file should go in `src/main/resources`, which will be included in the classpath in Maven builds. Since you're ignoring that part, you'll likely want to put it in the root of your source directory.

Comment: thanks a lot. this solved the problem. However, i get another error "no result defined for action and result success" any idea ?

Comment: @erencan Yep; your result's name is "SUCCESS", but `Action.SUCCESS` is the string `"success"` (lowercase). That's a guess, since I don't know what your action looks like. Also, `"execute"` is the default method and doesn't need to be specified. (And "success" is the default result name if you don't want to explicitly define it.)

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a `classes/` folder under `WEB-INF/` and put in your `struts.xml` file!

Answer (score 2):

Right click the project. Go to properties deployment build path and add all .jar files to /WEB-INF/lib.
 Then you shouldn't get this error.

struts.xml should be located under directory: src/struts.xml..

And WEB-INF/web.xml you we need to configure the struts based on filter..

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and got solution looking at tomcat log when restarting :  doctype were missing in `struts.xml`

so I added

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
```

now it works !

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by adding default-action-ref tag, for example,

```
<default-action-ref name="home" />
```

after package tag

in struts.xml

```
<package name="user" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

<default-action-ref name="upload" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was facing it because of not mentioning the namespace correctly in struts.xml.

I added the following snippet in the web.xml :

```
<welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
```

and also making the namespace as "/" default...
Hope it answers your query..

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to rename `Struts.xml` ---> `struts.xml`