# Struts2 'Required' field Validation Interceptors not working

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans, struts2

Building a login application (In Netbeans 731) which basically ensures non blank values for username and pw. The application runs fine except the validation doesn't work, so even if the user enters blank values they are taken to the `Thanks.jsp` page. After trying to build it as a Netbeans web app, I have rebuilt this application using Maven, with the following directory structure:

[image]

The generated war file is:

[image]

**`pom.xml`:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.manaar</groupId>
<artifactId>Maven8a2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Maven8a2</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.15.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

**`web/jsp/Required.jsp`:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>required Validator Example</title>
<style type="text/css">@import url(css/main.css);</style>
<style>
  .errorMessage {
color:red;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="global" style="width:350px">
<h3>Enter user name and password</h3>
<s:fielderror/>
<s:form action="Required2">
<s:textfield name="userName" label="User Name"/>

    <s:password name="password" label="Password"/>
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`web/jsp/Thanks.jsp`:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Thank you</title>
<style type="text/css">@import url(css/main.css);</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="global">
Thank you
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`WEB-INF/classes/app08a/RequiredTestAction.class`:**

```
package app08a;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class RequiredTestAction extends ActionSupport {
private String userName;
private String password;
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
}
```

**`WEB-INF/classes/app08a/RequiredTestAction-validation.xml`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
    "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
    "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">

<validators>
<field name="userName">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Please enter a user name</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
<field name="password">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Please enter a password</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
</validators>
```

**`WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="app08a" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="Required1">
        <result>/jsp/Required.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="Required2" class="app08a.RequiredTestAction">
        <result name="input">/jsp/Required.jsp</result>
        <result>/jsp/Thanks.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>

</struts>
```

**`WEB-INF/web.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    /web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5"> 

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Restrict direct access to JSPs. 
     For the security constraint to work, the auth-constraint
     and login-config elements must be present -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>JSPs</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
</web-app>
```

When I built this application manually (with Maven) it gave a stack trace due to wrong version of DTD tags. I no longer get this error after building the application using Maven.

When running this application I call the Required1.action. Even if I do not enter a password it skips straight to Action2 and the validation interceptor (`RequiredTestAction-validation.xml`) does not seem to be working.

Comment: Are you using struts2 plugin ? or just a maven project ? What version of jars are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Maven as per pom.xml above

Answer (score 1):

Required validator is a basic validator type and it checks for `null` field values. If you enter blank characters to the input fields it may not work. Use `requiredstring` validator instead.

```
<field name="userName">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Please enter a user name</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
<field name="password">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message>Please enter a password</message>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

The action class extends `ActionSupport`, it has default implementation of the `Action` interface required to return result after the action execution. And package extends `struts-default` that has `<default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>` and it inherited to your package.

Also, the [`FilterDispatcher` is deprecated since Struts 2.1.3](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/webxml.html).

Comment: I used the requiedstring type and changed to new struts filter. It's still having the same problems and producing the above stack.

Comment: You need to choose a correct DTD definition that corresponds to your version of Struts. Look inside the `xwork-core-x.x.x.jar` it contains `xwork-validator-x.x.x.dtd` that you should use with your `RequiredTestAction-validation.xml` or update libraries to the correct version of Struts.

Comment: I rebuilt this application using Maven (see above). I no longer get the stack error suggesting wrong DTD but the validation still doesn't work.

Comment: You should remove `security-constraint` and `login-config` because it's only "Restrict direct access to JSPs" and validation will not work.

Comment: i removed the security-constraint and login-config and validation still doesn't work

Comment: Did you forget to copy `RequiredTestAction-validation.xml` to the deployment place? It's a war in your case, I'd recommend to build war from the exploded folder and only in the case if you want to use Tomcat manager to deploy it manually. Build and work deploying in exploded mode.

Comment: I'm just showing the war as additional reference to the directory structure, but I'm building and running entirely in the IDE. Do you mean that I should copy the RequiredTestAction-validation.xml into the WEB-INF/classes folder? I assumed the IDE build would automatically do this

Comment: It looks very strange but you really need to do it, but if you "build entirely in the IDE" I think you have the issue with the ant build file, unless you use a maven build.

Comment: I'm using Maven to build but you're right I don't see the the xml validator in the WEB-INF/classes file

Comment: @jaytai You can put the `-validation.xml` to resources under the package name folder used by the action class.

Comment: It doesn't work when I do that. Maven just rebuilds it to the original structure when I run the build goal